# Hiding the fact that my website is built in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, html

I have developed a web application in ASP.NET 3.5 and C#. When I deploy the application, people can see the telltale signs that I'm using ASP.NET. How do I make it so that anyone who sees my site won't see that I'm using ASP.NET?

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Out of curiosity - Why would you want to hide the technology stack?

Comment: The only reason I can think of would be a security through obscurity rationale. Even if all identification was successfully removed from response headers, file extension and pages it would probably still be possible to determine it was asp.net by testing its response to various requests (e.g. asp.net request limit size).

Comment: @Steve, @Whiskey: this is sometimes done to make a would-be attacker's job just a little harder so as not to indicate the technology stack used. I forgot which podcast I listened to recently, but some sites went as far as using URL Rewriting to *keep* the `.asp` extension despite moving forward to ASP.NET MVC or webforms. IIRC their reason was partially motivated by not changing things for their users who have bookmarked things.

Comment: @Ahmad: Is it worth the pain? I mean it looks to me that we are doing way too much to achieve this. I mean , without viewstates, it could be a headache maintaining the page data between postbacks.

Comment: @Whiskey-Tango-Foxtrot: I don't think so. I think it's a hassle and weakens the developer experience for the sake of security through obscurity (as @Martin mentioned) since the developers need to work against the standard development approach of the framework. I would go with George's answer and move to MVC if possible. As far as broken bookmarks go, either tough luck for the users (woops, that page has moved or can't be found) or take the effort to parse the URLs and redirect users to the new locations where applicable.

Comment: Anyway, are there like 10.000 frameworks for building web-pages? Not really. There are several popular platforms at best, so the detection of the platform in itself is not a real issue, as any real attacker will suspect .net in minutes, no matter how good you hide it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of the nature of ASP.NET, any dynamically built control will show up with `$Ctrl`. If you use ViewState, that will show up. If you use ASP.NET Event Validation, that will show up.

If you don't want it to show up, all you can do is use another Framework (ASP.NET MVC), or not use any of those features of ASP.NET (Which would be silly if you're using ASP.NET).

If your pages are suffixed with `.aspx`, then everyone is going to know you're using ASP.NET anyway.  Are you using URL Rewriting?

Comment: Seems like disabling view state will work for me, in this case I am missing asp.net 4.0, in 3.5 I believe that I have to disable viewstate for the whole page and not for the specific control.
Am I correct?

Comment: Yes; you have to disable viewstate for the page. http://www.ironspeed.com/articles/Disable%20View%20State%20for%20a%20Page/Article.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend:

- Using a Url Rewriter to change or removing the page extensions
- Not using view State.

Comment: You might also suggest removing any indication of IIS or .NET from the HTTP headers returned.

Answer (score 1):

Defining telltale signs? Without looking at the source, the only obvious way would be the .ASPX extension.

Looking at the source, you'd need to remove

```
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" ...

    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

- Any references to WebResource.axd or ScriptResource.axd
- ASP.NET control names (ctl00, etc)
- Response Headers `X-Powered-By` and `X-AspNet-Version`

Can anyone think of others?

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to remove embedded resources. The .axd extenstions in the page source are a give-away.

Edit:
Coming to think of it, the hidden fields (ex. __EVENTVALIDATION) are give-aways too...

Answer (score 0):

Your only real choice is to switch to ASP.NET MVC; otherwise, there will be tells somewhere for anyone who really knows ASP.NET, or you'll be limiting the features you use to the extent that there's no benefit in using ASP.NET. Even without ViewState, if you have controls embedded in panels, or use master pages, control IDs will be give-aways. Any MS-specific JavaScript emitted by controls or by the page will be give-aways. Consistent use of a single form per page is pretty much a give-away.  Lots and lots of things indicate ASP.NET.

Why is this so important?